# ¿ Alternativa a clausula where IN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Si consulto ciertos datos en una consulta `where in`, me traería los datos que coinciden.

- Ejemplo: http://rextester.com/OZJX17754

Pero mi duda es ¿cómo obtengo los datos que **no coincidan** y me los arrojen en la consulta?

[image: Datos de ejemplo]

"Datos a consultar" es una lista al azar, no es una tabla, y de estos datos que quiero consultar no me interesan los que ya esta sino los que no están.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener los datos que coincidan y los que no en la misma consulta?

Comment: @jeissoni22 Depende de cómo estén los datos. Los "*Datos a consultar*" ¿son una tabla, son una lista predefinida, qué son? El opuesto a `IN` es `NOT IN`, pero no necesariamente es la opción más eficiente. `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` o `NOT EXISTS` suelen funcionar mejor, dependiendo del caso. Creo que deberías [edit] la pregunta dando un poco más de detalle de cómo es la estructura de la base y de dónde salen los datos.

Comment: @jeissoni Gracias por agregar más información, pero ¿qué es una lista al azar?... Comentaste que podrías obtener los resultados opuestos con `where in`. ¿Podrías mostrar el código que utilizarías para obtener lo contrario a lo que estás buscando? Creo que así se podría entender la pregunta

Comment: Hola Mariano. mira con una consulta where in normal y los datos que tengo en esta lista de ejemplo me traería (4,5,6) pero quiero me muestre (10,15,20)  ... http://rextester.com/OZJX17754

Comment: No mi amigo, usando el not in en el ejemplo traería 1,2,3,7,8

Comment: Sería bueno que pegues el código de la consulta que estás haciendo así desde ahí podemos ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder seleccionar las filas de números que se deseen, primero... bueno... tienen que estar en una tabla. `DATOS A CONSULTAR` debería ser una tabla dentro de la base de datos.

Si los valores se usan sólo para una consulta casual (o si se generan desde otro script), se puede generar una tabla temporal.

```sql
with datos_a_consultar ("NUMERO") AS (
    VALUES (10), (15), (5), (4), (6), (20)
)
```

Permitiendo usarlos como resultado de la consulta. Podríamos usar `NOT IN`, pero prefiero usar `NOT EXISTS` (que es más eficiente si la columna acepta nulls).

```sql
select "NUMERO"
  from datos_a_consultar
 where not exists (
            select 1
              from tabla
             where tabla."NUMERO" = datos_a_consultar."NUMERO"
        )
```

- [Demo en rextester](http://rextester.com/QPJA7245)

Comment: Hola Mariano, muchas gracias por su ayuda y tiempo, entonces en estrictamente necesario crear una tabla temporal? justo era lo que no quería hacer jeje, pero sino se puede pues ni modo

Comment: Exacto. Para obtener una tabla de resultado, el origen **tiene** que ser una tabla. En lo posible, recomendaría usar una tabla de la base, y usar una tabla temporal si estos datos cambian con cada consulta.

Answer (score 2):

> Nota: no he usado PostgreSQL y seguramente esta solución no sea muy eficiente, o haya maneras mucho más sencillas de hacerlo.

Una posible alternativa a lo que [recomienda Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29329/250) (personalmente optaría por eso) podría ser crear la tabla temporal *al vuelo*, usando la función [`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) y pasándole los valores como una cadena. Seguirías teniendo una tabla temporal, pero sería algo más aproximado a lo que parece que buscas.

El código sería algo así (lo puedes ver ejecutándose en este [Rextester](http://rextester.com/STW92387)):

```
SELECT *
FROM   CAST(regexp_split_to_table('10,15,5,4,6,20', E',') AS integer) tabla2 (id)
WHERE  id NOT IN ( SELECT "NUMERO" FROM tabla )
```